# Randomization test vs. t-test vs. others?

Tags: t-test, permutation-test

I am trying to find out if the means of two groups are different. I have performed a randomization test and found significant results but I would like to confirm it with some other test. I looked into the t-test, but it seems like a more limited but less computationally-intensive version of a randomization test.

Would it be of any value to perform a t-test after already having performed a randomization test? Are there any other alternatives for a test for the differences between the means of two groups?

Comment: In a permutation test, you can use various 'metrics' to express the differences between the two samples: pooled t statistic, Welch t statistic, difference in sample means, difference in sample trimmed mean, difference in medians, and so on.  Especially if assumptions for a t test are massively violated, a permutation test will give a different--more valid--answer (about rejection) than t test.

Answer (score 1):

Performing several tests of the same hypothesis can lead to some very sticky situations.  For instance, what would you do if you did a t-test and the test failed to reject the null?  Now, you have two conflicting tests and the question becomes "what do I do now?".  Not to mention that you open yourself up to making a false positive with higher probability.

My advice is to think carefully about what hypothesis you want to evaluate and use a statistical test which best fits your situation.  The t-test is a canonical statistical analysis for evaluating the difference in means between two independent groups.  I would prioritize that over other tests (assuming your data are consistent with the assumptions for the test).

Comment: I think the data fits the assumptions for the t-test, sort of. The distributions in the two groups look fairly normal (although both have a skew of 1 and one has a kurtosis of 1.5). This is one of the reasons I thought a randomization test would fit this situation better. But I did not realize that performing two tests on the same hypotheses can be problematic. I guess I will stick with the results of the randomization test. Thank you for your help!